# Select multiple rows of Gridview in one textbox C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I require multiple rows of the GridView to show in a single TextBox after selecting the row. I am able to select one row and display it in the TextBox and here is the code for it:

```
protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
    {
        txtConfirm.Text = "Course: " + GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[0].Text;
    }
}
```

This an example of what the select option does currently:
[image]

Could anyone help me with how I could keep selecting rows to the TextBox?

Comment: Your code is not clear can you share your files for better understanding

Comment: After your for loop you need some sort of If condition which checks if the row is selected and then print it on the textbox, seems you are missing some code here

Comment: @Harpreet Did you mean show multiple columns in a text box (of the selected row)?

Comment: @ChrisCatignani Yes that is correct, so I select one row and then that rows column is shown and then if I select another row it should add that columns data below the previous one selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was just working on this...so it may need a little tweeking. Make note of the special characters that need addressing.

```
public string GridtoCVS(GridView gvParm)
{
    StringBuilder sbRetVal = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i <= gvParm.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
    {
        StringBuilder sbLine = new StringBuilder();

        for (int j = 0; j <= gvParm.Columns.Count - 1; j++)
        {
            sbLine.Append(gvParm.Rows[i].Cells[j].Text.Trim() + ",");
        }
        string sLine = sbLine.ToString().Replace("&nbsp;", "").Replace("&#39;","'").Replace("&amp;","&");

        sbRetVal.AppendLine(sLine);
    }
    return sbRetVal.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Selects All Rows:** You can select get all rows data from your `foreach` row instead of `SelectedRow` as like:

```
String AllRows = String.Empty; // add all rows in this String variable

// Iterate to all rows of your gridview
foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
   AllRows += "Course: " + row.Cells[0].Text + "\n"; Add Current row the String

txtConfirm.Text = AllRows; // set String variable to the TextBox
```

**Persist TextBox data:** You can persist previous rows data in TextBox as like:

```
String AllRows = txtConfirm.Text; // add TextBox data in this String variable

// Iterate to all rows of your gridview
foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
   AllRows += "Course: " + GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[0].Text; + "\n";

txtConfirm.Text = AllRows; // set String variable to the TextBox
```

Comment: I understand the above selects all rows from the GridView, however I require a select few to be displayed not all.

Comment: Which few you want to select?

Comment: So if you see the screenshot I posted in the question, the select link in the last column allows me to only select one row and output that row to the TextBox. If I click another row it removes the previously selected row from the TextBox and replaces it with the newly selected row.  So for example, I require one row to be selected then outputted to the TextBox, and if another one is selected that will be added to the TextBox aswell.